# Create a unique 802.11 authentication method

Tags: security, authentication, raspberry-pi, wifi

Please any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I want to do: I want to authenticate a station with an AP using my own authentication method i.e. not using WPA or WEP. Then further create unique association terms. But I do not know how to create an authentication method or what specific files in the device to manipulate.

I would like to do this on two raspberry pi 3B+ (one as an access point and the other as the station).

Also, if there is a way to simulate this on MATLAB or any other means. I am very interested in both. Thanks in advance.

It's research and the clients will be designed to authenticate via the same method. As to what I've tried, I haven't been able to find any sources that provide meaningful information on either how to create the files needed to develop an authentication method on both the clients and the AP, or how to manipulate the files for WPA in packages like hostapd and wpa-supplicant.

I am trying to prove security.

The AP offers a set of new services, so the station sends a serviceRequest frame to the AP. AP responds with a serviceResponse frame subset of services offered. Station responds with an association request frame containing a certificate. AP validates the certificate with the database, under subset clause. Also, I would like to set the subtype and type bits, so it doesn't interfere with bits already in use. It's a four-step handshake. I hope that's clearer.

Comment: How would clients (devices) support this? Do you design those too, like some kind of a research?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Yes, it's research and the clients will be designed to authenticate via the same method. As to what I've tried, I haven't been able to find any sources that provides meaningful information on either how to create the files needed to develop an authentication method on both the clients and the AP, or how to manipulate the files for WPA in packages like hostapd and wpa-supplicant.

Comment: The AP offers a set of new services, so the station sends a serviceRequest frame to the AP. AP responds with a serviceResponse frame subset of services offered. Station responds with an association request frame containing a certificate. AP validates the certificate with the database, under subset clause. Also, I would like to set the subtype and type bits, so it doesn't interfere with bits already in use.

It's a four-step handshake. I hope that's clearer.